# Redirect, send and Fetch parameter in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a React application running on http://localhost:8080.
I am having another Express application running on http://localhost:8081

The express app has to redirect to react app along with a POST parameter.
I am able to redirect to different URL by below code

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.post("/", function(req, res) {
  res.redirect("http://localhost:8080/");
});

module.exports = router;
```

But, I am not able to figure out how to pass parameters along with reading the parameters at React end.
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pass data in a get params format instead of post

Comment: you can pass query paramater while redirect in. Like this res.redirect("http://localhost:8080/?params1=value");

Comment: I want to pass a token, so I don't want to pass it as a query parameter

Comment: May be you can check this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters

Comment: I tried passing body parameter as below

`var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
var token = "Token";
    
res.send(token);
});
    
app.listen(8080);
console.log("Server sending At http://localhost:" + 8080);`

Now, I am not able to figure out, how should i read this body from other express app e.g, http://localhost:8081